# Can a SSRS report open up in an Excel spreadsheet within SSRS rather than exporting it from SSRS to Excel?

Tags: reporting-services

We would like to have a SSRS report open up in an Excel spreadsheet within the SSRS environment rather than exporting it from the SSRS environment to Excel.  Is this possible?

Comment: Are you talking about opening an Excel spreadsheet, then having some code execute which kicks off a SSRS report, and import the results into the open spread-sheet?  If so, you *might* be able to do this in code in the newer Excel(s) not sure.  What you might be better off doing is creating an Excel spreadsheet, that when opened executes a SQL Query/Stored Proc which refreshes the report data.  I had a Spread Sheet which did this for a manager.  He had to be on the network of course for it to work, but served his purpose.

Answer (score 0):

You can take the report's URL and append &rs:Format=EXCEL on it. This will give you the report in Excel. The possibilities here are that you can write a small app that generated the URL you want with the parameter settings you want which then you can use Response.Redirect(url) to open it.

Besides that, you can write a more comprehensive application that simulates SSRS' parameter interface using SSRS Soap services framework. I'm actually 2/3 of the way done with doing this very thing and it works nicely.

Answer (score 0):

You could also just include the sql in excel! It would be missing the SSRS features, but if all you want is the data in Excel:

Data tab >> From Other Sources >> From SQL Server >> [enter server name] >> [select a database] >> Finish >> Properties >> Definition >>

At this point, change the "Command type" to be SQL and the Command text to your sql query. You may need to include these if you have temp tables:
SET ANSI_WARNINGS OFF; 
SET NOCOUNT ON;

(sorry, it takes a few steps to get there!)